# Spawning objects in javascript and deleting them

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm making a Javascript mini-game, theres a bad guy and the player, when the player is clicked on, he fires a bullet, the bullet goes to the bad guy, and upon hitting him it disappears, hurting him.

I managed to get to spawning the bullet, and I can make it move too, the problem is when trying to spawn more than 1 bullet (Shooting twice), that way every bullet will need a different ID, this is what iv'e tried to do:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var hp = 4;
var num = 1;

function fire()
{

    document.getElementById("bodie").innerHTML += "<img style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;' id='bullet"+num+"' src='../project1/images/bullet.png'/>";
    bulletpos();
    num++;

}
function fireanim()
{
    document.getElementById("player").src = "../project1/images/goodguyfire.png"
    setTimeout(function still(){document.getElementById("player").src = "../project1/images/goodguystill.png"},200);
}


function bulletpos()
{

    var bulletX = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left) - 20;
    var bulletY = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.top) + 35;
    document.getElementById("bullet").style.left = bulletX;
    document.getElementById("bullet").style.top = bulletY;
    setInterval(function(){bulletmove()}, 25);

}

function bulletmove()
{
    var bulletX = parseInt(document.getElementById("bullet").style.left);
    document.getElementById("bullet").style.left = bulletX - 10;
}

function hit()
{

    document.getElementById("hpbar").src = "../project1/images/hp"+ hp +".png";

    if(hp <= 0)
    {
        die();
    }

    if(hp != 0)
    {
        hp--;
    }


}

function die()
{
    var foeX = parseInt(document.getElementById("foe").style.left);
    document.getElementById("foe").style.left = foeX - 33; 
    document.getElementById("foe").src = "../project1/images/deadguy.png";
}

</script>
</head>
<body id="bodie">
<img id="player"  onClick="fire(),fireanim()" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:600px;" src="../project1/images/goodguystill.png"/>
<img id="foe"  style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:150px;" src="../project1/images/badguy.png"/>
<img id="hpbar" style="position:absolute;top:80px;left:120px;" src="../project1/images/hp5.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i tried to spawn a bullet with same ID, but different number near the ID, that way i can control every single bullet, and delete them after they hit the bad guy.
But it still doesn't let me do it, don't know why.

If there is a better way to do this ill happily accept it, feel free to correct my code or absolutely change it.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to use HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: The problem is with your `bulletpos` function. While you're indeed spawning bullets with different bullet[id], you're still moving the `bullet`. Try changing your `document.getElementById("bullet")` to `document.getElementById("bullet"+num)`. If that doesn't work, please put it at jsfiddle.net and we'll take it from there.

Actually.. it won't work, due to global num... Oh dear.

Comment: Oh what a clumsy mistake, it does work now, but there still is one problem. the function "bulletmove()" wont be able to move all the bullets together, if the id will keep changing, it can only handle 1 bullet at a time, if you rather to change the code without explanation ill happily send it to jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes - every time you're spawning a bullet, it increases the `num` value. The animations however need to be targeting initial objects, not the last ones. The solution is to make the `bulletpos` and `bulletmove` functions parametric.

Comment: Haven't I already made it parametric by adding the num?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've tidied up your code a little, and left only the elements that are the problem:

```
<body id="bodie">
    <div id="player"  onClick="fire()" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:600px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #ff0000"/>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
var hp = 4;
var num = 1;

window.fire = function()
{
    var bullet = document.createElement("div");
    bullet.style.position = "absolute";
    bullet.style.left = 0;
    bullet.style.top = 0;
    bullet.style.width = "5px";
    bullet.style.height = "5px";
    bullet.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
    bullet.id = "bullet-"+num;
    document.body.appendChild(bullet);

    bulletpos(bullet);
    num++;
}



window.bulletpos = function(bullet)
{
    var bulletX = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.left) - 20;
    var bulletY = parseInt(document.getElementById("player").style.top) + 35;

    bullet.style.left = bulletX+"px";
    bullet.style.top = bulletY+"px";
    setInterval(function(){bulletmove(bullet)}, 25);

}

window.bulletmove = function(bullet)
{
    var bulletX = parseInt(bullet.style.left);
    bullet.style.left = (bulletX - 10)+"px";
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jKqvx/

The error lies with trying to target always the last bullet with `bulletmove` function, as you have to target every bullet that's still moving. We do that by passing the created element (`bullet`) from one function to other. This way you don't need to track the ids, and if you'll remove the `bullet.id` line, the code will still function (as we're referencing) the objects.

Comment: Ok, this is much better than mine, but can you explain few thing you've done: **1.** why did you write <pre>window.X= function()</pre> and not <pre>function X()</pre>, is there a difference? **2.** I didn't understand what did the `document.body.appendChild(bullet);` do, can you explain? Otherwise thanks for helping.

Comment: 1. there's no difference. I've done that as jsfiddle had issues with writing `function X`. Overall, when you're creating functions you're, de facto, assigning them to window scope, so `function A(something)` == `window.A = function(something)`.
2. If you create an element using JS `document.createElement("div");` you still need to insert them into the DOM. `document.body.appendChild(bullet);` does just that - inserts the newly created element after the last child of document.body. I didn't use innerHTML as, well, it's not a really good way of manipulating DOM.

Comment: Got it, last unrelated question if you don't mind:  I didn't get what is jsfiddle about, do I use it to share my code or is it an editor like Notepad++, I'll start using it if it can correct my code.

Comment: If you post your code here, and it gets complicated, people won't really know what's going on in it. And moving the codes/libraries, setting a test environment to get working what you've got on your computer might get tedious. Thus, good practice is to provide an example of what you have somewhere where all people can access it - jsfiddle.net (and other similar services) does just that. This way, also, even if I didn't provide an answer, somebody else might contribute to what I've written. It just makes life easier :)